Expected value of the maximum of the absolute value of two random variables
I'm trying to solve some exercises on stochastic processes and expected values and I stumbled upon the following question, which i am unable to figure out:
Given a stochastic process $\{X(t), t > 0\}$, defined by $X(t) = At + B$ with two random variables $A$ and $B$ which are independent normally distributed random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, what is the expected value of $\max_{(t \in [0,1])}\{|X(t)|\}$?
I have already established that the maximum will be either at $t=0$ or $t=1$, depending on whether A is positive or negative. This leads to the following: $\max\{|At+B|, |B|\}$. I think then i should make some case distinctions, so for example when $A>-2B$, $t$ should be $1$. And when $-2B < A < 0$, $t$ should be $0$. But then I am having a hard time setting up the integrals and actually calculate them to determine the expected value and how to calculate that. Could anyone help me with this?

Exercise for you: prove that for $x,y\in\mathbb R$,
$$\max(|x+y|, |y|) = \left| y + \frac x2 \right| + \left|\frac x2\right|.$$
Therefore
$$\mathbb E[\max(|A+B|, |B|)]=\mathbb E\left[\left| B+\frac A2 \right|\right] + \mathbb E\left[\left| \frac A2 \right|\right].$$
Now both $\frac A2$ and $B+\frac A2$ are normally distributed with mean zero, and variance that you can calculate. Then use the mean of the folded normal distribution to calculate the above expectations.
